# Downloading File is stopped when screen is locked

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

In React native ios app when i am trying to download a file from a url the file is getting downloaded well when screen is on. if screen gets off the download is getting stopped and not resuming even after screen is on. i am using RNFetch blob for downloading the file.can any one help me out.

Comment: In native iOS we have NSURLSession which allow to download a file and any data in background. Look to this side.

Comment: How can i implement NSURLsession using react native